# A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected, when using Distinct

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-datasource

I have the following table:

[image]

I'm trying to create a new column using Dax language:

```
Column = DISTINCT('Edição'[País])
```

But I gott this error message:

```
A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.
```

The expected result is:

[image: enter ription here]

Comment: Calculated columns expect a scalar value per row but DISTINCT returns a table. What are you trying to achieve, be more specific in order to help you.

Comment: I added a new image in order to be more specific. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: In the second Brazil occurrence what should appear in the calculated column? I think the easiest way to get the distinct values is creating a calculated table, if that works for you I'll post an answer.

Comment: I don't want to add something on the missing occurences. I want to display this new column as a chart without countries names repetitions.

Comment: If you add `[País]` column to a chart it will automatically group the vales in distinct ones, I don't find a reason for do that in a calculated column.

Comment: Yes, I known that, but I want to do this for learning purposes

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, I created another question with more informations of what I am trying to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447290/count-occurences-in-dax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a source table with 21 rows. You want to add a column. In the end you'll still have 21 rows.

The "expected" table has 18 rows. So with only adding a column you will never get there, it's just impossible.

To get the expected output though, you can do this easily: just create a table with just `Pais` as values and PowerBI will automatically group. See here a (more minimal) example:

[image: Example grouped table]

PS. If you wanted to add a column -say- with the number of years the country appears in the source data, you should:

- choose the *matrix* visualization
- add "Pais" (country) for rows
- add e.g. "Ano" (year) for values, and summarize by "Count (Distinct)"