# Count occurrences in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-datasource

I have the following table:

[image]

Now, I want to apply some dax instructions to that table, and display this data in a chart:

[image]

Or in other words, I if it is the first time that the Country's name appears, it must show `1` and `2` for the second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for creating a calculated column called `Occurrences`:

```
Occurrences =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( [Pais] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        [Index] <= EARLIER ( 'Table'[Index] )
            && [Pais] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Pais] )
    )
)
```

Index must be an incremental key in each row.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Can you exaplain me what is happening on your code?

Comment: @Caaarlos. Sure, In the index: 0 - Pais: Uruguay row it takes the whole table and filter the rows which Index is less or equal to 0 and Pais equal to Uruguay and count them using the COUNT function, so it counts only one  Uruguay value. Then pass to the second row index: 1 Pais: Italy and filter the rows which index is less or equal to 1 and Pais equal to Italy, in your example one row. then pass to the third row and do the same... and so on. The most important concept here is the `EARLIER` usage, [check this article](http://tinylizard.com/dax-earlier-function/) I used to understand it.

Comment: Thank you, @alejandro zuleta. I realy appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

List.Count(Text.Split(Text.From([#"Name"]), "naveen"))>1